# Getting negative cosine distance using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cosine-similarity

I am using `tf.losses.cosine_distance(Y, outputs, axis=2, reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN)` to measure the difference between my labels and predictions. The tensor shape is `[batch_size, sequence_length, embedding]`. In my case, the shape of the prediction is `[16311, 20, 100]`.

My result is as follow.

```
----------------------epoch1----------------------
train 1  loss 1.1429076
----------------------epoch2----------------------
train 2  loss 0.51511204
----------------------epoch3----------------------
train 3  loss -2.5750072
----------------------epoch4----------------------
train 4  loss -6.685198
----------------------epoch5----------------------
train 5  loss -10.863398
```

The boundary of cosine similarity is `[0,1]`. But in my case, it is larger than 1 at the beginning and became negative after several epochs. I wonder why these could happen.

My embedding contains negative numbers. Should I normalise it before calculating the cosine distance?

Answer (score 1):

First, yes, you should normalize before computing cosine distance: (from the documentation)

> Note that the function assumes that predictions and labels are already
>   unit-normalized.

However, the range of the cosine similarity function is not `[0,1]`. Consider the vectors `(1 0)` and `(-1 0)`. Both are unit vectors and their cosine similarity is `-1`.

Finally, notice that the loss is computing cosine distance, which is 1 minus cosine similarity because the optimization operation for losses is minimization and not maximization (as would be appropriate for cosine similarity). So you would expect to get negative numbers getting increasingly bigger in absolute value.